# Get all the variable names or attributes of a @interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want all the variables names or attributes of a interface or class in objective c.

I am able to get and set the value for a variable dynamically using valueForKey: message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get all 'properties' for a class, you can utilize the Objective-C runtime to get this data:

```
unsigned int propertyCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);

for(i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
}

free(properties);
```

With this object you can get all of the metadata associated with a given property.  This isn't for the faint of heart though (and it is a C based API).  Determining information about each property (like it's policy and type) isn't simple.

Comment: do i need to include any header files or any other settings?

Comment: worked out by including the below headers #import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: I should have mentioned that - but you only need: #import <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) and in particular the `class_copyIvarList` and `class_copyPropertyList` functions. Use of these runtime functions should be what you're looking for.